# Change MUI TextField border-color

Tags: material-ui, styled-components

I want to change the border color of the material UI `TextField` Component when it gets focused without using a theme that wrapps the entire app.
I am using styled components and nextjs in my project and the [official documentation](https://material-ui.com/guides/interoperability/#styled-components) is not leading anywhere.

I inspected the TextField and tried to apply changes directly by adressing the class. Without any effect.

```
const StyledInput = styled(TextField)`
  width: 100%;
  &.MuiInputLabel-root.Mui-focused {
    color: white;
  }
`;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer depends on what variant of text field you are using. 
 
**If you are using 'standard' variant:**

```
const StyledInput = styled(TextField)`
  width: 100%;
  & .MuiInput-underline::before {
    border-color: yellow !important;
  }
  & .MuiInput-underline::after {
    border-color: orange;
  }
`;
```

**if you are using 'outlined' variant:**

```
const StyledInput = styled(TextField)`
   width: 100%;
   & .MuiOutlinedInput-notchedOutline {
      border-color: red;
   }
   & .MuiOutlinedInput-root.Mui-focused .MuiOutlinedInput-notchedOutline {
      border-color: orange;
   }
`;
```

You can see working example at https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-pu652?fontsize=14

Answer (score 0):

this works for me

```
import React from "react";
import TextField from "@material-ui/core/TextField";
import styled from "styled-components";

//use this with variant="outlined"
const StyledInput = styled(TextField)
  width: 100%;
  & .MuiOutlinedInput-notchedOutline {
    border-color: red;
  }
  & .MuiOutlinedInput-root.Mui-focused .MuiOutlinedInput-notchedOutline {
    border-color: orange;
  }
`;



export default function OutlinedTextFields() {
  return (
    <form noValidate autoComplete="off">
      <StyledInput
        id="outlined-name"
        label="Name"
        value="test"
        margin="normal"
        variant="outlined" //use with first styled input
        // variant="standard" //use with second styled input
      />
    </form>
  );
}
```